# bash: how to update an associative array in an implicit subshell?

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, associative-array, subshell

The problem: I cannot update an array in a `while` loop. An illustration (*not* the actual problem):

```
declare -A wordcounts
wordcounts["sentinel"]=1000
ls *.txt | while read f; do
  # assume that that loop runs multiple times
  wordcounts[$f]=$(wc -w  $f)
  echo ${wordcounts[$f]}  # this prints actual data
done
echo ${!wordcounts[@]}  # only prints 'sentinel'
```

This does not work, because the loop after the pipe runs in a subshell. All the changes that the loop does to variable `wordcounts` are only visible inside the loop.

Saying `export wordcounts` does not help.

Alas, I seem to *need the pipe* and the `while read` part, so ways to rewrite the code above using `for` is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a legitimate way to update an associative array form within a loop, or a subshell in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have a complex command pipe you're reading from, you can use the following:

```
while read f; do
    # Do stuff
done < <(my | complex | command | pipe)
```

The syntax `<(command)` runs a command in a subshell and opens its stdout as a temporary file. You can use it any place where you would normally use a file in a command.

Further, you can also use the syntax `>(command)` to open stdin as a file instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `bash` 4.2, you can set the `lastpipe` shell option to allow the while loop, as the *last* element in the pipeline, to run in the current shell instead of a subshell.

A simple demonstration:

```
$ echo foo | read word
$ echo $word

$ set +m  # Only needed in an interactive shell to disable job control
$ shopt -s lastpipe
$ echo foo | read word
$ echo $word
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a legitimate way to update an associative array form within a
>   loop, or a subshell in general?

You could avoid a subshell by saying:

```
while read f; do
  ...
done < *.txt
```

That said, you sample code has problems otherwise.  The loop would read the file line by line, so saying

```
wordcounts[$f]=$(wc -w  $f)
```

wouldn't really make much sense.  You probably wanted to say:

```
wordcounts[$f]=$(wc -w <<< $f)
```

EDIT:

> Alas, I seem to need the pipe ...

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines):

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell (see [Command Execution Environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment)).

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the pipe; actually I have a more complex thing than `ls` on its left side. Updated the question to clarify. And no, `while read f` does read filenames from the pipe, not file lines from `f`.

Comment: You can still use the same technique with a complex command. At the end, instead of `done < *.txt`, use `done < <(my | complex | command | pipe)`

Comment: @Cookyt: please make your comment into an answer, since it's what actually solves my problem and I'd like to accept it.

Comment: @9000 You could use a named pipe.  `mkfifo myp; command1 | command2 > myp &; while read ... done < myp`

Answer (score 0):

Why use `ls` unnecessarily.

Following works fine:

```
declare -a wordcounts
for f in *.txt; do
    wordcounts+=$(wc -w  $f)
done
echo ${wordcounts[@]}
```

Comment: `ls` is for illustration here, it's not the actual problem. Your solution is nice, but I actually need the pipe and the `while read` loop, so...

Comment: Fact that you were using pipes it was changing array's values in in a sub-shell. That can only be avoided by avoiding piped command.

Comment: You also need to remember the fact array values are exported to sub shells.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is the one by Cookyt:

```
while read f; do
    # Do stuff
done < <(my | complex | command | pipe)
```

For me, that didn't work because in my environment I don't have `/proc` mounted because the `<(cmd)` construct needs `/dev/fd/XXX` and `/dev/fd` is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd`. In those cases, the solution by by chepner works:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
my | complex | command | pipe | while read f; do
    # Do stuff
done
```

If you also don't have bash, there is a third solution that works with POSIX shells (and thus also with bash):

```
set -- $(my | complex | command | pipe)
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    f="$1"
    shift
    # Do stuff
done
```